# What Are The Best Width Ranges for Media Queries in laptops and cell phones

Tags: html, css, fixed-width

I was wondering what the right parameters of width ranges to insert in my code would be for larger devices like tablets and laptops and then smaller deices such as cellphones in a responsive design?

Comment: It depends on the content, but you can take a look at the values defined by bootstrap for example [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Comment: You could search about your question before but this can still be helpful. https://www.mydevice.io/#compare-devices

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect element within your browser (Chrome, Edge) and click the Toggle Device Emulation icon (looks like a phone and tablet) you can see what Microsoft and Google define them as.

- 4K - 2560px
- Laptop L - 1440px
- Laptop - 1024px
- Tablet - 768px
- Mobile L- 425px
- Mobile M - 375px
- Mobile S - 320px

Bootstrap defines them [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).